# Limit points of $\{n + 1/m :m,n \in \Bbb N\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

[image]

my approach is 
" Clearly 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,....... are only limit point of the sequence. Since limit point are the natural no. i.e. set of natural no’s and they are countable. Thus limit points are countable in no.’s."
Am i right ?

Comment: It's not really a _sequence_ if you have two independent indices...

Comment: but can't we have two independent sequence in addition ?

Comment: @PriyaWadhwa We can, but that will *not* be a sequence.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Is one of the two variables fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Note that what you wrote means that not only the answer (A) is correct but that the answer (D) is correct too.